# How to load image from web service in swift without memory warning

Tags: swift, image, load

How to load image from web service in swift without memory warning. What is the most ideal way of loading image from web service? I tried with SDWebImage but my app shows memory recieved warning.

[image]

Comment: What is the size of the image you're trying to download?

Comment: There is sample https://github.com/orazz/ImagesSlideshow

Comment: Post the code and not screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `NSData` and `UIImage` like this

```
guard let
    url = NSURL(string: "PUT_THE_WEBSERVICE_CALL_HERE"),
    data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url) else { return }
let image = UIImage(data: data)
```